# How to normalize a non-jquery event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

jQuery normalizes events properties across browsers, Is there any way to make jQuery normalize an event object that was not triggered by jQuery itself?

For example:

```
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("click", function(eventObject) {
   console.log(eventObject);
}, true);
```

`eventObject` is not normalized here, but I can not use `jQuery.on()` in this case because I need the event to trigger in the capture phase, not the bubbling phase. I want this `eventObject` normalized by jQuery.

Comment: How is it not normalized? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `Error: evenObject is undefined @ line 2:16`

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery to bind the event?  What problem did you have when you tried to use `jQuery.on()`?

Comment: @Rocket, questioner wants to handle the event during the capture phase. jQuery can only bind handlers to the bubbling phase.

Comment: @rac jQuery normalizes event properties by making them the same across all browsers. Some browsers do not adhere to the spec. More info: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery normalizes events using (*undocumented, so prone to change in the future*) `jQuery.event.fix` and you can use it in your code:

```
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("click", function(eventObject) {
   var jqNormalized = jQuery.event.fix( eventObject );
   console.log(jqNormalized ); // jQuery.Event {...}
}, true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghkfhg5d/1/

Comment: This is the right answer, but keep in mind that `$.event.fix()` is not documented. It is an implementation detail that can change or disappear overnight.

Comment: Whta @FrédéricHamidi said is an important info, but still, when you change the version of a library used in your project you should read the changelog ;)

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should open an issue in the jQuery issue tracker to make this method public?

Comment: Also note that reading the changelog may not be enough to see that jQuery.event.fix still exists. That should instead be a unit test that you include with the rest of your unit tests for this project. Opening an issue may not be a bad idea.